# Прогресс бар для разархивирования файлов, использую Ionic.zip (C# .Net)

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, ionic, dotnetzip

Как сделать прогресс бар для распаковки архива? Использую Ionic.dll. Вот пример кода распаковки:

```
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(_filename))
            {
                zip.ExtractAll(_extractpath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                zip.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Winforms или WPF?

Comment: Я помню делал через одну библиотеку так: Брал список файлов архива и циклом проходился по нему, делая +1 к счетчику, вот и прогресс был. Потом перешел на чуть другой способ - я изначально брал вес всех файлов и после, когда 1 файл распаковывался, я прибавлял вес файла к переменной, ну и был прогресс по типу `[РаспакованоКБ]/[ВсегоКБ]`. Вот собственно так и выкрутился из такой ситуации. Если ваша библиотека не имеет встроенных механизмов, то скорей всего нужно писать такой механизм, взяв за "счетчик" некую единицу (файл, размер итд).

Comment: @aepot Winforms

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, но там встроенное вроде бы что-то было. Я просто никак найти не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `ZipFile.ExtractProgress`.

```csharp
private async void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(p => progressBar1.Value = p);
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int oldProgress = -1;
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(_filename))
            {
                int currentEntry = -1;
                int totalEntries = zip.Entries.Count;
                zip.ExtractProgress += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Extracting_BeforeExtractEntry)
                        currentEntry++;
                    else if (e.TotalBytesToTransfer > 0)
                    {
                        int newProgress = currentEntry * 100 / totalEntries + (int)(e.BytesTransferred * 100 / e.TotalBytesToTransfer / totalEntries);
                        if (newProgress != oldProgress)
                        {
                            progress.Report(newProgress);
                            oldProgress = newProgress;
                        }
                    }
                }

                zip.ExtractAll(_extractpath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Вызывать `Dispose()` не нужно, `using` вызовет его сам там, где закрывающая фигурная скобка.

Comment: Код писал с мобильника, мог где-то опечататься.

Comment: В принципе я подправил знаки, но мне всё время кидает message box ошибку: "Попытка деления на нуль."

Comment: @Сергей я исправил эту досадную ошибку :)

Comment: Вы просто отец русской демократии,  спасибо огромное, только есть ещё одна просьба. Он показывает прогресс для каждого файла, а можно для всего архива или вы не можете с этим помочь?

Comment: Если не хотите, я приму ответ. Ещё раз спасибо. Жду ответа.

Comment: @Сергей ща что-нибудь придумаем, просто с мобилы медленно ищется, и решения находятся в основном костыльные.

Comment: Можно уменьшить вложенность кода на 1 уровень если использовать новую форму using: `using ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(_filename);`